# How to replace * to <> in the string using java

Tags: java, string

Original : `abc*d*ef*xyz*`

After: `abc<d>ef<xyz>`

I try to replace all star to a pair of <> using java, i try to use replaceall(), but it just replace one single thing. how can i replace in pair?

Comment: Have you tried to replace them in a for loop ?

Comment: how about two `replaceAll()`

Comment: `String str = "abc*d*ef*xyz*".replaceAll("(\\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\*)", "<$2>");`

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through each character and create a new string:

```
  String str ="abc*d*ef*xyz*";
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
   char ch = '<';
   for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
       if(c == '*') {
           c = ch;
           ch = (ch=='>'? '<': '>');
       }
       sb.append(c);
   }
   System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Or just use `new StringBuilder(str)`, and set the character instead of appending. Or just operate on the array returned by `toCharArray`. At the very least, pre-size the string builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following loop:

```
String str = "abc*d*ef*xyz*";

char nextReplace = '<';
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    boolean find = false;
    if(str.charAt(i) == '*') {
        find = true;
        str = str.substring(0, i) +nextReplace +str.substring(i+1);
    }

    if(find) {
        if(nextReplace == '<') {
            nextReplace = '>';
        }else {
            nextReplace = '<';
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(str);
```